# Can Xamarin.forms target android 14 ( sdk 34)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to update my app to target android 34 as given by offical announcement (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin)

I tried changing the manifest file directly to support sdk 34 but on building apk for release its giving error as highest target version is 33 .

Answer (score 0):

I tested the Xamarin project and it can run on the Android 14. You can change the sdk version to 34.

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
```

Xamarin support will end on May 1, 2024 for all Xamarin SDKs including Xamarin.Forms. Android API 34 and Xcode 15 SDKs (iOS and iPadOS 17, macOS 14) will be the final versions Xamarin will target from existing Xamarin SDKs (i.e. no new APIs are planned). It is recommended that you can use the MAUI or migrate the project to the MAUI.